# How to scrape all article links from Reuters website using Scrapy when older links are dynamically loaded after scrolling down?

Tags: scrapy

I am trying to scrape all the hyperlinks of the website for all the news articles to extract the content. I am able to retrieve all the data from all the articles which are loaded when you open the website but when you scroll down on the site more articles are automatically loaded due to an event. Currently I am using Scrapy_Splash but I receive the same amount of links when I do not use splash. I hope you can help me out. The spider is called class FinanceNewsScraperSpider(scrapy.Spider):. Below you can see my code:

```
name = "audinewsarticles"

def start_requests(self):
    start_urls = ['https://www.reuters.com/companies/NSUG.DE/news',
                  ]
    
    urls = start_urls
    
    for url in urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_newspage)

def parse_newspage(self, response):
    links = response.xpath('//a[contains(@href,"/article/")]/@href').extract() #extract hyperlink
    for url in links:
        yield SplashRequest(url=url,
                            callback=self.parse_article,
                            endpoint='render.html')

def parse_article(self, response):
    item = AudiItem()
    item['article_link'] = response.url
    item['article_headline'] = response.xpath('//*[contains(@class,"ArticleHeader_headline")]/text()').extract()
    item['article_date'] = response.xpath('//*[contains(@class,"ArticleHeader_date")]/text()').extract()
    item['article_text'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="StandardArticleBody_body"]//p/text()').extract()
    
    print(item)
    
    #saving data to file.
    path = 'news/'
    file = 'audinews_' + str(datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M")) + '.csv'
    file_name = open(path + file, 'a')

    fieldnames = ['article_link', 'article_headline','article_date','article_text'] #adding header to file

    writer = csv.writer(file_name, lineterminator='\n')
    writer.writerow([item[key] for key in item.keys()])
```

Please let me know if you need more information from me.

Comment: Data of this website is fetched from an API which makes your scrape 10x faster, when you scroll down you will see in XHR tab a new request which gets you the data in a formatted JSON

Comment: Thanks for the reply but how can I solve my issue knowing this?

Comment: just make the request directly to the API instead of the website, then parse the JSON response

Comment: I understand that makes total sense. I am quite new to scrapy tho don't I need some kind of api key to request any kind of data via scrapy then?

Comment: I could call the API like this https://wireapi.reuters.com/v8/feed/rcom/us/marketnews/ric:NSUG.DE?until=1525773864023892000 but it just shows me soem articles and when I try like this https://wireapi.reuters.com/v8/feed/rcom/us/marketnews/ric:NSUG.DE? I just get the latest one and not all if them. Sorry for all the questions but I am a bit confused right now.